# how to get short natural answers from internet?

Tags: nlp, google-search, nlp-question-answering

Does it exists a version from google or wikipedia or other servers offering short answers to you questions?

I'm coding an assistant like Siri and I'd like to be able to ask him who is the president of the united states and get something like: Barak Obama (confidence: 0.8345) or similar

Is there something offering this kind of answers out there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a search engine that will give a direct answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941580/is-there-a-search-engine-that-will-give-a-direct-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The professional name for the task you are looking for is "question answering".
These websites provide good question answering for free:

- [https://www.google.co.il/search?q=who+is+the+president+of+the+us](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=who%20is%20the%20president%20of%20the%20us)
- [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=who+is+the+president+of+usa&lk=4&num=1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=who%20is%20the%20president%20of%20usa&lk=4&num=1)
- [http://start.csail.mit.edu/answer.php?query=who+is+the+president+of+the+US%3F](http://start.csail.mit.edu/answer.php?query=who%20is%20the%20president%20of%20the%20US?)

About the problem in general:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering